# How to run Valgrind to find out memory leaks on my Embedded MIPSEL- linux box?

Tags: mips, valgrind, embedded-linux

How can I run valgrind on an embedded Linux box to find memory leaks in my main software?

In the `rcS` script, I am running like this:

```
./main_app
```

How can I associate the `./main_app` program with valgrind? The main_app process never terminates.

I want to constantly log the data to file. Also, I want to access the log file without terminating the `main_app` process. I can do telnet and can access the log file. But the problem is until and unless the handler is closed, how can I open the file i.e. I don't quite understand which valgrind parameters control how memory leaks are logged to file. Please help!

Answer (score 7):

You can try to build it by your own for mips, here the steps:
download valgrind from here http://valgrind.org/downloads/ - I used Valgrind 3.8.1
unpack archive with valgrind and move to the valgrinds folder
execute:

```
./autogen.sh
./configure --host=mipsel-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/pub/valgrind CFLAGS="-mips32r2" CC=/opt/toolchains/mips-4.3/bin/mips-linux-gnu-gcc CXX=/opt/toolchains/mips-4.3/bin/mips-linux-gnu-c++
./make -j6
./make install
```

- **prefix** - folder to install compiled binaries of valgrind;
- **CC** and **CXX** - path to compilers;
- **CFLAGS** - "-mips32r2" and "-mplt" flags should be passed to compilers if it older then gcc (GCC) 4.5.1

on target mips box export path to valgrind lib folder:

```
export VALGRIND_LIB=/mnt/nfs/lib/valgrind
```

Now you can use it as usual, for memory checking features you can look here http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html
It works for me, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Valgrind only works on x86.  You can still track down your leak if you build your application for x86 and run it under valgrind there.  Its unlikely the problem is specific to the target architecture.

Comment: No, I can't build my application for X86.

Comment: Valgrind supports Mips since v3.8.0 - see http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html

Answer (score 0):

The answer above describes how to build valgrind but to actually get a full leak check as opposed to just a list of memory problems, your program does have to terminate, I am guessing you never terminate your program.

Assuming your process is some kind of daemon process your best bet is just run it in a loop, monitor memory usage using something like `top` and then when you see signs of excessive memory usage send it a shutdown command somehow. If you then run valgrind with the following options, you will get a unique log for each process run, including a dump of leaks at exit:

```
while true ; do
  valgrind --leak-check=yes --log-file=/tmp/log.%p.txt main_app
  sleep 1
done
```

The `%p` in the filename inserts the process id.

You can also specify `--show-possibly-lost=no` which will reduce the volume of leaks reported to those that valgrind has a much higher degree of confidence are lost.